# Generate class diagram Eclipse with Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, uml, eclipse-3.6

I have a Android project for which I want a class diagram. What is the best way to do this? I have installed the MoDisco, GEF, UML2 Extender. Are these sufficient? What is the simplest way to generate a UML from the classes with activities I already have?

Comment: have u find any way because i have same problem, i don't no how to do it or witch is batter(MoDisco, GEF, UML2 Extender)..

Answer (score 1):

Try Object aid plugin for eclipse. http://www.objectaid.com/